# Clunking and shimmying when braking after rack replaced

Tags: brakes, rack-and-pinion

My rack and power steering pump were replaced last week (rack had a leak and the pump ran dry). Since getting my car back, I've noticed shimmying when braking (the harder I brake or faster I'm going the more pronounced it is). In addition, when I brake at lower speeds I hear a clunking from the right front wheel. It sounds similar to a bad CV joint, but it's related to braking rather than turning. I don't notice it at higher speeds, though I don't know if it's simply covered by road noise.

They did a full inspection and didn't report any other issues. The tires are new, about 3500 miles. They rotated them and did an alignment with the other work.

This is a 2009 Subaru outback, 5 speed manual.

My assumption is they had to take much of the front end apart to replace the rack - is this correct?  What might've gotten put back together incorrectly to cause this? I'll be taking it back to them to fix but would like to know likely causes first. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's hard to give exact answers without the make, model and year of the car. Is it front wheel drive or rear? It definitely sounds like they didn't do the job right, I wouldn't accept any additional bills on this.

Comment: Gah, right. It's a 2009 Subaru outback, 5 speed manual